# Animating circle stroke SVG - Not a full circle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, jquery-animate

Hi guys I am having trouble animating a stroke on an SVG where I only want it to be a 3/4 circle as the math is more complex!

Basically I want to pass a percentage in a function (0-100) and have the line animate to the correct place. So 33% would show one quarter of the stoke in green and 100% would show 3/4 of the stoke in green.

I have a pen here and you can change the offset in the JS animate to get different results.

```
$(".percentage").animate({"stroke-dashoffset":"78"}, 3000);
```

so "78" would be 100% and "314" would be 0% but I am lost at how I can map this!

[**CodePen Demo**](https://codepen.io/RMCreate/pen/VKLdxa)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: and whats the number for 50%?

Comment: 314 is 50(radius)*2*3.14

Comment: and 78 is just because 314/4

Comment: Well 50% 100/50  = 2. Then 392 / 2 gives me 196. But if I try with 70% i'ts different so 100/70 = 1.42 then 392/1.42 = 276 which is visually about 10%. How can I get the formula to work as my numbers are backwards!

Comment: Change the function to see the result https://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkWRPg

Comment: see my answer below. you need 151 for 2/3 complete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was how I did it...

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/kkWRPg

```
function percentage($percent) {
    var offsets = 314.1593 - ($percent * 2.3562);
  return offsets;
}

var offset = percentage(75);
$(".percentage").animate({"stroke-dashoffset":offset}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

- 0%   : radius*2*3.14   (318)
- 100% : 0 (full circle) (0)
- 75%  : radius*2*3.14*(1-75%) (78)

So you need radius*2*3.14*(1-P*75%) for your result

for example, you need 318*0.5*0.75 for 50%

Here is the (hope it's easy to understand) function for you

```
function percentage($percent) {
    var arc = 0.75;
    var radius = 50;
    var min = radius*2*3.14/*PI*/;
    var max = min*(1-arc);
    var multiplier = $percent/100;
    var position = min+(max-min)*multiplier;
    return position;
}

var offset = percentage(100);
$(".percentage").animate({"stroke-dashoffset":offset}, 3000);
```

Comment: My question now is how do I work out that "/2" 50% is easy 100/50 = 2 but for 70% it doesn't come out correctly

Comment: At least for your Example in question, now I am looking at your code in comment.

Comment: I change your code and post in the answer, please check if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var length= 314-78;
fuction toPercentage (number){
   return Math.round(((314-number)/length)*100);
}
```